# Use domain group for ACL C#

Tags: c#, windows, active-directory, acl

I have four groups in my active directory:

- ReadOnly
- Users
- Managers
- Partners

And, I have a Windows Server (2012) which contains some folders:

- Administration
- Public
- Restricted
- Planning
- Ressources

How can I use these AD groups to apply access rules on this server in my C# app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do it !

AD groups have this properties :

```
group.properties["objectSID"];
```

I use it to :

```
SecurityIdentifier readOnlySID = new SecurityIdentifier(group.Properties["objectSID"][0] as byte[], 0);
```

And finally :

```
FileSystemAccessRule(readOnlySID, FileSystemRights.Read, AccessControlType Allow);
```

This is the only way to manage ACL for an AD group !

Answer (score 0):

**I've already made the program Insert your data to C# and export to Powershell file and run it**

[image]

Here is the powershell code for write Rights

```
$acl = Get-Acl "\\Server\Testshare"
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($False,$false)
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule('Server_Testshare_local','modify','ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit','None','Allow')
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
Set-Acl "\\Server\Testshare" $acl
```

And Read Rights

```
$acl = Get-Acl "\\Server\Testshare"
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($False,$false)
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule('Server_Testshare_Read local','ReadAndExecute','ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit','None','Allow')
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
Set-Acl "\\Server\Testshare" $acl
```

And C#
[image]

Comment: I would like to only use C# :/

Comment: @BaptisteMarcos Sorry man, Wouldn't know a way to do this w/o powershell

Comment: @BaptisteMarcos   Do you want to look here?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780010/sharing-a-folders-permission-in-c-sharp